# What should I learn before I dive into ubuntu-touch porting and development?

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-touch, documentation

The documentation is a bit over my head. While I can understand the syntax for the most part, I have a hard time comprehending why specific parts, such as cyanogen mod, are important to the project, or whether they are permanent mainstays to the project. I feel like I would benefit from more basic documentation before I dive in, but I do not know where to start, and what documentation is good to know long term.

I am thinking that I should just hop into kernel development, but I would like to hear what others think.

My goal here is to become a long term Linux and Ubuntu developer, familiar with its low level aspects.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that you will get much better answers to these particular questions on the [Ubuntu Phone Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone)'s mailing list, as well as the #ubuntu-phone IRC channel on Freenode. If you haven't already, also have a look at [Developers get the full support they need](http://insights.ubuntu.com/resources/article/developers-get-the-full-support-they-need/).